# Multiple organisational accounts on SSO device

Tags: okta, duosecurity

I am a software contractor and for the first time will have two clients at once. I am wondering if my SSO (Okta and Duo) can support multiple organisations independently on a single mobile device? Or, is it best to buy two phones if using the same app for multiple clients?